# I want both table and text at the center of page and table cell resp

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\normalsize
\centering

\begin{document}
\section{Data sheet}
Department of Mechanical Engineering\\
\flushleft
\textbf{1. Name}                                                     : Sandip R. More\\
\textbf{2. Registration No.}                                   : ME12S037   \\
\textbf{3. Registered for}                                      : MS By Research \\
\textbf{4. Specialization}                                       : Machine Design\\
\textbf{5. Category}                                                : Regular\\
\textbf{6. Guide}                                                     : Prof. P Chandramouli\\
\textbf{7. Date of joining}                                     : 16 July 2012\\
\textbf{8. Date of Registration}                           : 16 July 2012\\
\textbf{9. Date of GTC Meeting}                          : 25 September 2013\\
\textbf{10. Area of Research}                               : Floating Raft Vibration Isolation\\                                            
\textbf{11. Details of course work}                     :\\ 
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline  \textbf{Sr No.}&\textbf{Course No.} &\textbf{Course  title}  &\textbf{Semester}  &\textbf{core/Elective}  &\textbf{Credit}  &\textbf{Grade}  \\ 
\hline  1& ID 6020 & Introduction to Research& Jul-Nov 2012  & Compulsory  & 2  & P  \\ 
\hline 2 &  ME 7360  & Theory of Vibration & Jul-Nov 2012 & Core & 3 &  B  \\ 
\hline 3 &  ME 6700  & Advanced Mechanics of Solid & Jul-Nov 2012 & Elective &  3 & B  \\ 
\hline  4 & ME 6003 & Variational Principles in Mechanics & Jul-Nov 2012 &  Elective &  3 & B  \\ 
\hline 5 &  ME 7840 &   Signal processing of Mechanical Systems &   Jul-Nov 2012 &  Elective &  3 & B  \\ 
\hline 6 &  ME 7850 &   Modal Analysis of Mechanical System  & Jan-May 2013 &   Core & 3 &  A  \\ 
\hline 7 &  ME 6800 &   Finite Element Analysis &   Jan-May 2013 &  Core &  3 & A  \\ 
\hline 8 &  ME 6000 &   Computational methods in Engineering &  July-Nov 2013 & Elective &  3 & Crediting  \\ 
\hline  9 & ME7710 &    Advanced Vibration and Acoustics &  July-Nov 2013 &  &  3 & Auditing  \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could be a bit clearer about you want to achieve.  In your example, the contents of all table cells are centered, and the table is centered on the page (except that the table is too wide for the page; removing a column reveals that it is centered).  So what, exactly, is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have too wide a table, so you need to decrease its width; I suggest splitting the course names into two rows.

Some points to note before presenting the code.

1. `\flushleft` is not a documented command; it exists, but should not be used. However, setting `\parindent` to zero seems better in this case.
2. Don't do `\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}`, because a font changing command will not respect it. Rather use something like `\linespread{1.5}` in the preamble.
3. Don't end lines with `\\`, even in this case; reserve it for environments where endlines must be specifically indicated.
4. You don't need to enclose a `tabular` in a `table`, which is for floating objects.
5. With `booktabs` the table will be better, see later.

In order to squeeze the table, I did some trial and error for reducing `\tabcolsep` by a small amount. Also I changed the margins to be equal, in order to better show what happens, but it's by no means necessary. I also removed the header for the first column, which only adds to the width without bearing any information.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{%
  \linespread{1}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}\strut#2\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Data sheet}
Department of Mechanical Engineering

\textbf{1. Name}:                 Sandip R. More

\textbf{2. Registration No.}:     ME12S037

\textbf{3. Registered for}:       MS By Research

\textbf{4. Specialization}:       Machine Design

\textbf{5. Category}:             Regular

\textbf{6. Guide}:                Prof. P Chandramouli

\textbf{7. Date of joining}:      16 July 2012

\textbf{8. Date of Registration}: 16 July 2012

\textbf{9. Date of GTC Meeting}:  25 September 2013

\textbf{10. Area of Research}:    Floating Raft Vibration Isolation

\textbf{11. Details of course work}:

\begin{center}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-.7pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  &
  \textbf{Course No.} &
  \textbf{Course  title} &
  \textbf{Semester} &
  \textbf{Core/Elective} &
  \textbf{Credit} &
  \textbf{Grade} \\ 
\hline
1 & ID 6020 &
  \splitcell{Introduction to\\ Research} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Compulsory & 2 & P \\ 
\hline
2 &  ME 7360 &
  \splitcell{Theory of\\ Vibration} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Core       & 3 & B \\ 
\hline
3 & ME 6700 & 
  \splitcell{Advanced Mechanics\\ of Solid} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\hline
4 & ME 6003 & 
  \splitcell{Variational Principles\\ in Mechanics} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\hline
5 & ME 7840 &
  \splitcell{Signal processing of\\ Mechanical Systems} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\hline
6 & ME 7850 &
  \splitcell{Modal Analysis of\\ Mechanical System} &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\hline
7 & ME 6800 &
  \splitcell{Finite Element\\ Analysis} &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\hline
8 & ME 6000 &
  \splitcell{Computational methods\\ in Engineering} &
  July-Nov 2013 & Elective   & 3 & Crediting \\ 
\hline
9 & ME7710 &
  \splitcell{Advanced Vibration\\ and Acoustics} &
  July-Nov 2013 &            & 3 & Auditing \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version with `booktabs`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{%
  \linespread{1}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}\strut#2\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Data sheet}
Department of Mechanical Engineering

\textbf{1. Name}:                 Sandip R. More

\textbf{2. Registration No.}:     ME12S037

\textbf{3. Registered for}:       MS By Research

\textbf{4. Specialization}:       Machine Design

\textbf{5. Category}:             Regular

\textbf{6. Guide}:                Prof. P Chandramouli

\textbf{7. Date of joining}:      16 July 2012

\textbf{8. Date of Registration}: 16 July 2012

\textbf{9. Date of GTC Meeting}:  25 September 2013

\textbf{10. Area of Research}:    Floating Raft Vibration Isolation

\textbf{11. Details of course work}:

\begin{center}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-.7pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\toprule
  &
  \textbf{Course No.} &
  \textbf{Course  title} &
  \textbf{Semester} &
  \textbf{Core/Elective} &
  \textbf{Credit} &
  \textbf{Grade} \\ 
\midrule
1 & ID 6020 &
  \splitcell{Introduction to\\ Research} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Compulsory & 2 & P \\
\addlinespace[3pt]
2 &  ME 7360 &
  \splitcell{Theory of\\ Vibration} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Core       & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
3 & ME 6700 & 
  \splitcell{Advanced Mechanics\\ of Solid} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
4 & ME 6003 & 
  \splitcell{Variational Principles\\ in Mechanics} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
5 & ME 7840 &
  \splitcell{Signal processing of\\ Mechanical Systems} &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
6 & ME 7850 &
  \splitcell{Modal Analysis of\\ Mechanical System} &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
7 & ME 6800 &
  \splitcell{Finite Element\\ Analysis} &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
8 & ME 6000 &
  \splitcell{Computational methods\\ in Engineering} &
  July-Nov 2013 & Elective   & 3 & Crediting \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
9 & ME7710 &
  \splitcell{Advanced Vibration\\ and Acoustics} &
  July-Nov 2013 &            & 3 & Auditing \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant using `tabularx`. I have kept the use of `booktabs` from [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133435/4686), and his `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-.7pt}` but I have removed the `\splitcell` command: the idea is not to have to choose the locations of the `\\` and let the `TeX` paragraph building algorithms do the job.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Data sheet}
Department of Mechanical Engineering

\textbf{1. Name}:                 Sandip R. More

\textbf{2. Registration No.}:     ME12S037

\textbf{3. Registered for}:       MS By Research

\textbf{4. Specialization}:       Machine Design

\textbf{5. Category}:             Regular

\textbf{6. Guide}:                Prof. P Chandramouli

\textbf{7. Date of joining}:      16 July 2012

\textbf{8. Date of Registration}: 16 July 2012

\textbf{9. Date of GTC Meeting}:  25 September 2013

\textbf{10. Area of Research}:    Floating Raft Vibration Isolation

\textbf{11. Details of course work}:

\begin{center}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-.7pt}
\linespread{1}\selectfont
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc>{\centering}Xcccc}
\toprule
  &
  \textbf{Course No.} &
  \textbf{Course  title} &
  \textbf{Semester} &
  \textbf{Core/Elective} &
  \textbf{Credit} &
  \textbf{Grade} \\ 
\midrule
1 & ID 6020 &
  Introduction to Research &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Compulsory & 2 & P \\
\addlinespace[3pt]
2 &  ME 7360 &
  Theory of Vibration &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Core       & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
3 & ME 6700 & 
  Advanced Mechanics of Solid &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
4 & ME 6003 & 
  Variational Principles in Mechanics &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
5 & ME 7840 &
  Signal processing of Mechanical Systems &
  Jul-Nov 2012  & Elective   & 3 & B \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
6 & ME 7850 &
  Modal Analysis of Mechanical System &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
7 & ME 6800 &
  Finite Element Analysis &
  Jan-May 2013  & Core       & 3 & A \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
8 & ME 6000 &
  Computational methods in Engineering &
  July-Nov 2013 & Elective   & 3 & Crediting \\ 
\addlinespace[3pt]
9 & ME7710 &
  Advanced Vibration and Acoustics &
  July-Nov 2013 &            & 3 & Auditing \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered reduced table]